# CFFILEUPLOAD not shows up when called with AJAX (CF9)

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

For an image-gallery I am using a simple AJAX script to load content into a modal div (http://www.developersnippets.com/2009/05/20/evaluate-scripts-while-working-on-ajax-requests/).

I would like to use the file upload using cffileupload (CF9) in the same modal div. When loading the cfm-file with the cffileupload-tag in it using ajax, the upload dialog doesn't get loaded. When I run the cfm-file without ajax, it works.

I already tested it whit different ready-to-run ajax-scripts. They basicly run, but only the cffileupload-dialog doesn't get loaded.

After wasting several days maybe someone can give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I am pretty sure you cannot upload files using AJAX - though, I think it can be done with HTML5 (at least in some browsers).

Answer (score 0):

I think the underlying issue is the SWF for CFFILEUPLOAD is failing to load up or render within the modal window.  I am not a user of CFFILEUPLOAD so do not know what the fix for this would be but have you considered possibly using something else to upload the files?  Here is just one example online of how to upload files via Ajax:

http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/

It is not via a modal window but may find it easier to take something like that and get it working within a modal.